# CSS styling conflict prevention and namespacing techniques

Tags: html, css, namespaces, widget

Say you're building a conceptual widget named Awesome Widget and you want to completely protect it from conflicting with either surrounding elements or child elements that reside as content inside the widget.

**What we don't want**

```
div ul li {}
```

**Solution 1: CSS child combinator**

Using the CSS child combinator selector to specify that only direct children should be targeted.

```
.awesomewidget > div > ul > li {}
```

**Solution 2: class namespacing**

Using aw (Awesome Widget) as the namespace for each class, decreasing the chance of any other elements on the page using that exact namespace + classname.

```
.awesomewidget .aw-container .aw-list .aw-listitem {}
```

There's also something like @namespace in CSS but that's only for XML.

Besides solution 1 and 2, are there any others that can be used? Which one would you prefer? Any best practises?

**EDIT: example of a problem that arises without proper namespacing / styling conflict prevention**

Widget styling:

```
.awesomewidget > div ul li {
background-color:red;
}
```

User styling:

```
ul li {
background-color:blue;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="awesomewidget">
<div>

<ul>
<li>
<!-- user content starts here -->

<p>I am the user and I want to add some content here. Let's add a list:</p>

<ul>
<li>Why is this list-item red and not blue?</li>
</ul>

<!-- user content ends here -->
</li>
<li>
<!-- user content starts here -->

<!-- user content ends here -->
</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to use a combination of the two solutions like:

```
.awesomewidget > div ul li {}
```

Because the second one adds a LOT of unecessary weight to the markup.

## Update

For your example, I would add a wrapper around the user content with class `.user` and then prepend their CSS with `.user`.  However, this is not graceful, it adds some markup, and I think it would be prone to failure.

Comment: I can see your point. But what about content inside the li (could be any element in a non conceptual widget) that's not part of the widget itself (the content) and is styled by somebody else?

Comment: @DADU My brain just exploded.  Content that is inside the widget, but is not part of the widget and is styled by someone else.  What does this mean?

Comment: @rockerest I should clarify this. Say you're building a tabs widget. You have the tab buttons but you also have the tab sections. Inside each tab section, the user can add its own HTML content and style it. So the widget is just a frame.

Comment: @DADU sure, but can't that content just be accessed via the parent `.awesomewidget`?  So any content, no matter what content, as long as it's under `.awesomewidget` is considered a part of the widget.  You'll have to elaborate on an example of a problem that might arise if I'm still not understanding the issue.

Comment: @rockerest Problem example is added to the original question.

Comment: @DADU I see the problem, and I can't find a very graceful solution.  I'll update my answer with what I've got, but it's not great

Comment: @rockerest Thank you for your not so graceful solution! Your input is really appreciated. Wouldn't you rather go with solution 1 then because it's on the widget side, so the user has no extra hassle?

Comment: @DADU yes absolutely.  However, if it ever becomes too clunky to target direct children, then I would go with a namespaced CSS.  basically, my only concern is creating a lot of extra code, so in most cases, Solution #1 would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

[XBL](http://www.w3.org/TR/xbl/) might help if it ever gets implemented in browsers as it has ways of designing widgets which can avoid passing on styling information.

Another advantage, btw, to including the child combinator is performance. It does not need to check all levels of possible children to determine how to render.

But if you're going to do class-namespacing for brevity, two at most should be enough I would think, unless you're not naming distinctly enough:

```
.awesomewidget .aw-listitem {}
```

You could also give a container (with a well namespaced class) to the non-user content section(s) at the highest level possible which does not enclose the user content, saving yourself from that risk. `<div/>` is pretty handy for that kind of arbitrary grouping and made for that purpose...

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing many CSS namespacing conflicts, maybe it's time to consider switching to a front-end JS framework like Facebook's [ReactJS](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope). This, in conjunction with [Webpack Module Loader](https://webpack.github.io/), will allow you to leverage many fine JS libraries that will streamline your development workflow. [CSS-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader), for example, will help you manage your CSS development by doing [local scoping](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope), which is just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solutions:

- Check the source order to make sure that global styles are linked before the page specific styles in the head
- Use [target](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/mozilla/target.html) to trigger user CSS
- Use [generated content](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/content-gallery.html) to bind styles
- Use [attribute selectors](https://css-tricks.com/css-for-blockin-stuff/) to increase specificity