# twitter-bootstrap and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap only for slides but it sets the width for even othr things.in this my con div is taking container-fluid width and not taking my specified width.why it is like that.

```css
body
{
margin:0px;
}
#wrapper
{
width:100%;
height:auto; 
margin:0px;
background-color:orange;
}
#header
{
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
background-color:black;
right:0px;
z-index: 100;
}
#header
{
top:0;  
}
#footer
{
left:0;
right:0;
z-index: :100;
width:100%;
height:48px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
}

#footer img
{
float:right;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
} 

.company
{
  width:50%;
  height:60px;
  color:white;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px;
}
.navbar
{
height:60px;
width:50%
background-color:black;
color:white;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;

}

 ul li
{
display: block;
position: relative;
padding:10px 15px;
float:left;
}
ul li a
{
color:white;
}
.navbar a:hover
{
 border-bottom:3px solid red;
  padding:18px;
 
}
.active 
{
background-color:grey;
}
#myCarousel
{
background-color:white;
height:370px;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img 
  {
      width: 70%;
      height:15%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color:white;
  }



.thumbnail
{
height:300px;
width:300px;
padding:25px auto;
margin:5px;

}
#con
{
width:100%;
height:300px;
}
.contact
{
width:60%;
height:300px;
background-color:grey;
padding:100px;
float:left;
}

.enquiry
{
width:40%;
height:300px;
background-color:seagreen;
float:left;

}
input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
input[type="text"] 
{
 margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>student</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@media only screen and (max-device-width:320px)
{
images
}
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-device-width:480px)
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px)
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1224px)

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!--start wrapper-->
<div id="header"><!--start header-->
<div class="company"><!--start company-->
ABC PVT LIMITED
</div><!--end company-->
<div class="navbar"><!--start nav-->
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="home.html"/>Home</li>
<li><a href="about.html"/>About us</li>
<li><a href="services.html"/>Services</li>
<li><a href="products.html"/>Products</li>
<li><a href="contact.html"/>Contact us</li>
</ul>
</div><!--end nav-->
</div><!--end header-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!--carasel start-->
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"><!--start carosel inner-->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="../task/photo/h.jpg" alt="Home">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Home</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="../task/photo/as.jpg" alt="About us">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
             </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../task/photo/s.jpg" alt="Services">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Services</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../task/photo/p.jpg" alt="Products"> 
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Products</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../task/photo/c.jpg" alt="Contact us">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
             </div>
    </div>
  
  </div><!--carosel inner end-->

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!--end carosel-->

<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey"><!--boxes-->
  
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
        <p><strong>Innovation</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
        <p><strong>Creativity</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
        <p><strong>Positivity</strong></p>
              </div>
    </div>
</div><!--end boxes-->


<div id="con"><!--start con-->
<div class="contact"><!-- start contact-->
<h1>Address</h1>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
Abc private limited
no54,2ndstreet,
madipakkam,
chennai-67.
</p>
 <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> ABCPVT@gmail.com</p>
</div><!--end contact-->
<div class="enquiry"><!--start enquiry-->
<h1>Enquiry Form</h1>
<table border="0" align="center">
<form name="form" action="email.php" id="form" method="post">
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td><input name="phone" placeholder="phonenumber" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Message</td>
<td><textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea></td>
</tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

</div><!--end enquiry-->
</div><!--end con-->
</div><!--end wrapper-->
<div id="footer"><!--start footer-->
copyrights &copy; to WWW.abcpvt.com
<img src="../task/photo/fb.png" alt="fb"/>
<img src="../task/photo/ln.png" alt="tweet"/>
<img src="../task/photo/tw.png" alt="linkedin"/>
</div><!--end footer-->









</body>
</html>
```

is that not possible to use both bootstrap a little and html css to make a proper webpage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we cannot restrict css file so that it will applied to only a section of html. If you want to do that you have to modify the all the classes inside the file to have a container.
Check this [CSS styling conflict prevention and namespacing techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127608/css-styling-conflict-prevention-and-namespacing-techniques)

Better option will be first start developing with bootstrap and override style where ever you need.